# Trying to convert jquery plugin to Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Within a loop, I have:

```
<div class="barcode" class="thumbnail"> 
  <canvas class="ean" barcode-generator barcode-value="9002236311036"> </canvas>
</div>
```

Which loops out a load of barcodes. I've statically added the barcode-value, but the intention is for this to be added via {{barcodeNumber}}

I've found a really nice plugin https://github.com/joushx/jQuery.EAN13 which converts a number to a barcode.

Following various tutorials, I've written the following Directive (although I don't quite get the HOW or WHY as yet). I've also included jquery above Angular, and the plugin after Angular.

```
app.directive('barcodeGenerator', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    barcodeValue: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
    $('.ean').EAN13(scope.barcodeValue);
  }
}
});
```

The console.log works - but then the bit where I call the plugin doesn't... Chrome debug displays the following error:

TypeError: Object 9002236311036 has no method 'split'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - have read lots of forum posts, but can't quite grok it.

Thanks,
Rob

Edit - following on from Francisco's post below - adding toString() has worked. Only thing is, I don't know why / how this is working.

```
app.directive('barcodeGenerator', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    barcodeValue: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
    $('.ean').EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
  }
}
});
```

So I've done a little refactoring:

```
app.directive('ean', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'C',
  scope: {
    barcodeValue: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, elem) {
    console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
    $(elem).EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
  } 
}
});
```

- I wanted to clean up my html, so used a class (restrict C?) - set the barcode value within the scope.

Then in my html, I added:

```
<div class="barcode" class="thumbnail"> 
  <canvas class="ean" barcode-value="{{barcode}}"> </canvas>
</div>
```

And this is where it errors... the barcode-value. Before it was hardwired and worked... now I try to put it in the loop, it doesn't.

Edit...

```
<div class="barcode" class="thumbnail"> 
  <canvas class="ean" barcode-value="barcode"> </canvas>
</div>
```

Removing the curly brackets worked.... hmm... I need to get a manual...

Comment: Split is part of the String Object in javascript. If 9002236311036 is an integer, it will not have access to the split method. Maybe try turning it into a string first?

Comment: Thanks - that works :) I added toString on the end and it functions well. I still don't know why it works though...

Comment: Glad it helped! Do you mean you don't understand how directives work?

Comment: yep - I see lots of different ways of implementing them. Mostly examples without any explanation. I read that they're a way to extend html... but I still don't quite get why you'd want to do that as well?

Comment: Let me post an answer for this since it'll be a little more lengthy than a comment will allow...

Comment: Thanks - I'll give mark it as correct for you've got this working for me :) I've just tried to refactor my code - and have another error, so will add that too.

Comment: Curly brackets don't work for =, you will need to use @ instead.

Comment: I am the author of the barcode library and I would like to finally implement angular.js support right in the library. It would be nice if comebody could test [the branch](https://github.com/joushx/jQuery.EAN13/tree/angularjs) and can give me feedback on [the issue](https://github.com/joushx/jQuery.EAN13/issues/24).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directives are a way to extend HTML. The whole purpose behind doing this is that AngularJS encourages to keep all DOM manipulation outside of controllers so they become testable.

I won't get into detail of how exactly directives work, it's possibly both the most powerful and most confusing aspect of AngularJS.

In short though, referring to what you've done:

```
app.directive('barcodeGenerator', function () {
    return {
        // Restrict tells AngularJS how you will be declaring your directive in the markup.
        // A = attribute, C = class, E = element and M = comment
        restrict: 'A',
        // The directive compiler actually happens before the $scope is available in AngularJS, therefore
        // You need to pass certain values into your scope. In this instance, you are passing the barcodeValue
        // attribute and telling it its equal. In other words where you use scope.barcodeValue.toString() below
        // You are able to do this because of the below declaration. There are other symbols you can use to tell
        // the compiler to do other things such as interpret the values as a method, but I'll let you investigate
        scope: {
            barcodeValue: '='
        },
        // The link function passes the element to the directive and allows you to manipulate the dom
        // You could event try to replace $(.ean) with just elem below, since you are passing the scope,
        // element and attribute to the function below, then using the jQuery plugin to do the rest.
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
            $('.ean').EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best explanation I've read so far, and a great starting point for me to look into each property.

Comment: Glad to help Rob. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

The francisco.preller is absolutely right. Just one improvement is required. If you change

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
        $('.ean').EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
    }
```

with

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
        elem.EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
    }
```

Not only it becomes more angularized, but it also follows the role of the 'elem' parameter, which is already a jQuery object (or jQLite, which is a jQuery subset, if jQuery is not loaded). Any use of direct DOM manipulation is said to be a bad practice by Google, as it could not always be reflected in Angular's digest cycle and will cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get something similar to work  with no success..the barcode will just not display..do you have all your code on github to use?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't.... but I do have working bits and bobs on my drive. I'll add the code here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this library for the barcode: https://github.com/joushx/jQuery.EAN13

```
app.directive('ean', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'C',
  scope: {
    barcodeValue: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
    console.log("Recognized the barcode directive usage");
    $(elem).EAN13(scope.barcodeValue.toString());
  }
}
});
```

and

```
<div class="barcode" class="thumbnail" ng-show="voucher.barcode">
<canvas class="ean" barcode-value="voucher.redemptionCode"> </canvas>
</div>
```

and if I recall correctly - any number you pump in gets converted to the barcode (although its been over a year since I did this... )

Hope this helps