# Bootstrap datepicker modify to take two dates

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive

I would like to convert bootstrap datepicker for angular: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js

so that it will behave something like this: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

I am not completely new to angular, but could someone tell me how hard it will be to convert bootstrap datepicker to allow select two dates? OR change multidatepickr into Angular directive?

Comment: The Angular-UI-Bootstrap project converted the Bootstrap Datepicker to an Angular directive already: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  if it doesn't do what you entirely want, perhaps you can fork the Github lib and add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out dangrossman's [Bootstrap-Daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker). It's an extension on Bootstrap's date picker to select a date range between two selected dates.

In terms of converting the multidatepickr jquery-ui plugin that you linked, there's a number of tutorials online about how to convert jquery plugins to angular directives. You can read up on using this [example](http://blog.thousandeyes.com/creating-extensible-widgets-part-1-jquery-to-angularjs/) or this related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127725/trying-to-convert-jquery-plugin-to-angular-directive)

Comment: Thanks Alex! DateRangePicker seems pretty solid and seem to do the job perfectly! Thanks!